# WordPress File Upload always give PHP.ini error

Tags: php, wordpress, file, upload

Using the media_sideload_image method (save from URL) works well, but for a actual uploads using the WP function *array(1) { ["error"]=> string(1) "s" }* it always gives me the following message.

> { ["error"]=> string(212) "File is empty. Please upload something more
>   substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled
>   in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than
>   upload_max_filesize in php.ini." }

Which clearly means there was an error - why? I have looked at the PHP INI file and it doesn't appear to be that, is there another means of setting it?

**PHP Code**

```
$upload_photo = $_FILE['upload_photo'];
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
 echo $upload_photo;
 $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
 $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $upload_photo, $upload_overrides );
  if ( $movefile ) {
      echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
      var_dump( $movefile);
  } else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
  }
```

**HTML Code**

> input type='text' value='Photo URL' id='upload_photo_url'
>   name='upload_photo_url' onclick="clear_field('upload_photo_url');"
>   />

**PHP Settings (printed from phpinfo())**
[image]

Comment: Well start with what the error suggests.  What is the result of running `php -i | grep upload_max_filesize` and `php -i | grep file_uploads` on your server?  Why don't you post some of those php.ini settings in your question.

Comment: @stakolee As I mentioned, the error given doesn't correlate with the PHP ini file. I.e. they are the same size. I've added a screenshot of phpinfo though none the less :)

Comment: Can you vardump the $_FILE var?  It should be an array so echo'ing it out shouldn't really show you anything. That may help us figure out what is going on.

Comment: No I can't, it returns NULL :/

Comment: @tim.baker Any luck with this one? I'm hitting the same issue now and I'm stumped.

Comment: @AndyAdams Unfortunately no. I tried everything I could and set everything I tried but I came to the conclusion it was my host. I am on a VPS so thought it wouldn't effect it, but it seems it does -so I had to create a work around.

Comment: @tim.baker I solved it in my particular case: There was another plugin that was hooking into the `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` filter and modifying/removing the file I was trying to upload. Dunno if that'll help in your case (but I hope so)!

Comment: @tim.baker what was your work around?

Thank you!

Comment: I never did get to the bottom of it I seem to recall ... reworked what I was doing totally

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a file called phpinfo.php
2. Save that file in your top level directory. Type yoursitename.com/phpinfo.php into the address bar and you will get a listing of all php information.
3. Once you know where to find and save the file php.ini, either on your host server or local host, open that file and search for 'post_max_size' and 'upload_max_filesize'. Change both to the maximum file size that you need to upload and save.
4. Upload the modified php.ini file to the directory you discovered with your phpinfo.php file. You will want to restart your localhost server and refresh the page. Uploading large files can now be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue fixed by adding the following code into the `<form>` tag.

`enctype="multipart/form-data"`